# Python how to read a complex list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a .txt that looks like this:

```
"uc007ayl.1"  "ENSMUSG00000041439"

"uc009mkn.1"  "ENSMUSG00000031708"
```

etc.

my codes are:

```
f = open("my dir"/"file name.txt", 'r')
r = f.readlines()
```

I print the read it shows something like this:

```
'uc007ayl.1\tENSMUSG00000041439\ruc009mkn.1\tENSMUSG00000031708\ruc009mkn.1\tENSMUSG00000035491\ruc007aft.1\tENSMUSG00000025907\r etc.'
```

I checked with list length by using the codes:

```
listlength = len(r)
```

it comes back with a length of 1 whereas there should be 3000 lines in my files. What is the problem?

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: Edit your question to include that. And post the ACTUAL code, not an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want each line to be a separate list item:

```
with open(r"filename.txt", "r") as f:
    mylist = [line for line in f]
```

Assuming you want each "name" to be a separate list item:

```
with open(r"filename.txt", "r") as f:
    mylist = [name for name in line.split("\t") for line in f]
```

**[EDIT]**

Based on what's being printed, perhaps try this?

```
with open(r"filename.txt", "r") as f:
    mylist = f.read().split("\r")
```

It looks like each line in your file is delineated by the `\r` character, which is a bit unusual.  In that case, I'd try manually splitting the file by that character and seeing if that works.

Comment: yes, now it reads like this:'uc007ayl.1\tENSMUSG00000041439', 'uc009mkn.1\tENSMUSG00000031708', 'uc009mkn.1\tENSMUSG00000035491', 'uc007aft.1\tENSMUSG00000025907', 'uc008xjp.1\tENSMUSG00000031558', 'uc009nip.1\tENSMUSG00000031730', 'uc008qjt.1\tENSMUSG00000015522',

Answer (score 0):

I normally use python 3, but I think I can help you on this:
Looking at your code and its results, `readlines` appears to simply return all the data in the file. I'd do the following (assuming file contents are string `fc`):

```
tlist=fc.split("\n")
dat=[]
for(s in tlist):
    dat.append(s.split("\"))
```

I'd use a list expression, but I honestly don't know if they work in 2.7.

Comment: We really don't know the problem due to lack of information, however, using list comprehension, you could compress this to: `dat = [s.split('\') for s in fc.split('\n')]`

Comment: I tried your code but I cannot do the split function, it said AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'